# filtration by string attributes sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx

Is there any way to use filtration with string attributes in sphinx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "No"

See this [post](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=6724) from the Sphinx forums

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to filter by string attributes.

For example, you have field author_name. Do the following in PHP:

```
$sphinx->SetMatchMode ( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 )
$sphinx->Query('@author_name "Mark Twain" ', 'myindex');
```

This code will find all documents which contain "Mark Twain" in author_name field.

*I am using double-quotes to find exact string.*

Comment: This worked for me, but the attribute must be declared as *sql_field_string* instead of *sql_attr_string* in the source config. This involves full text search support on the attribute and thus string attribute filtering". See http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

In sphinx mysql query convert the value of the field to crc32

```
SELECT crc32(field_name) as field_name FROM table
```

and add the field

```
sql_attr_uint = field_name
```

than when you build your query filter by crc32 checksum

```
$sphinx->SetFilter ( 'field_name', array(crc32($string_value)) );
$sphinx->Query('something', 'myindex');
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found interesting workaround in thinking sphinx site, may be it will be helpful for somebody http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#string_filters